# SNPs mapping into protein

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, snp

Starting a new project on protein-protein interactions and SNP analysis tool development. I would like to ask how does SNPs is mapped into protein? What does mapping means?

Comment: I assume SNP means Single-Nucleotide Polymorphism? I'm confused exactly what your question is - how does one take a SNP and see what effect it has on the protein sequence? Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well SNPs are [single nucleotide polymorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism). Some SNPs are in the coding regions of genes and they can result in changes in the resulting protein. For example, the SNP [rs1801131](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=1801131) is a human variation where some individuals have a G instead of an A at position [1515](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/nuccore/NM_005957.4?report=graph&v=1015:2015&content=5&m=1515!&mn=rs1801131&dispmax=1&currpage=1) of the gene [MTHFR](http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/gene/MTHFR). When the gene is transcribed and then translated into protein, this variation (the presence of the G nucleotide) causes a Glutamate residue at position [429](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/protein/NP_005948.3?report=graph&v=379:479&content=5&m=429!&mn=rs1801131&dispmax=1&currpage=1) of the protein to be a Glycine instead.

So, SNP rs1801131 maps to position 429 of the protein MTHFR.

Comment: @MattDMo you've got a dirty mind... :)